# React-select : dynamic change Option label when selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Below I have a react-select component, with label as +{ctryCode}{ctryName}

[image]

```
<Select
  options={countryProvinceCityList}
  value={telCtryObj}
  onChange={handleTelCountryChange}
  getOptionValue={(x) => x.telCode}
  getOptionLabel={(x) => '+' + _.padEnd(x.telCode, 5, '\u2007') + x.desc]}
/>
```

When an option has been selected, I would like to change its label from

+{ctryCode}{ctryName} to +{ctryCode} , e.g. from '+1 USA' to '+1'

while the available option labels remain the same.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to overwrite the component with the following code:

```
const SingleValue = props => (
    <components.SingleValue {...props}>
      &#43;{props.data.telCode}
    </components.SingleValue>
  );

<Select
  ...
  ...
  components={{ SingleValue }}
/>
```

Comment: I honestly didn't understand what you just did, I'm new to reactJS, can you please explain what you did here? I'm facing the same problem and I'm tryna find a solution.